# ListItem.Value overwrites Text if not set

Tags: c#, asp.net

If you set `ListItem.Value` to a value before setting its `Text` value, both `Text` and `Value` will be set to the same value. I can get around this, but I just want to know why this happens? Is it because something "must" be set to the screen? And why overwrite when the default is an empty string.

.Net 3.5

```
ListItem li = new ListItem();
li.Value = "abc"; //Text is now = "abc"
li.Text = "def";
li.Value = "qwe"; //Text remains "def"
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that before your first assignment Text is actually string.Empty and not null?

Comment: @DavidePiras, it's not that I am unsure of my code snippet, but this is the EXACT code I ran to test this theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the getter of the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.text.aspx) property is implemented in this way:

```
get
{
    if (this.text != null)
    {
        return this.text;
    }
    if (this.value != null)
    {
        return this.value;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

MSDN:

> Use the Text property to specify or determine the text displayed in a
>   list control for the item represented by the ListItem. Note **If the
>   Text property contains null, the get accessor returns the value of the
>   Value property**. If the Value property, in turn, contains null,
>   String.Empty is returned.

The [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is the other way around:

> If the Value property contains null, the get accessor returns the
>   value of the Text property. If the Text property, in turn, contains
>   null, String.Empty is returned.

Comment: so by this code, the text property should return the second value property that was set. and he said it doesn't.. the text property still remains

Comment: @Elior: Why? He has set the Text property before he sets the second value property. So at this time the getter of `Text` returns the actual text. Only if one of these properties is not set, this property returns the other (already) set property. If both properties are null, string.empty is returned. This is a common pattern if two properties are related and at least one should be returned.

Comment: While I don't agree with this design, I will just have to keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @gunr2171: This design is predefined from html. A `ListItem` will be rendered as option tag. The _label_ attribute is the text indicating the meaning of the option. If the label attribute isn't defined, its value is that of the element text content. The _value_ attribute represents the label explaining the option. If it is not defined, its default value is the text content of the element. So ASP.NET just transfers this behaviour to the serverside.