# ASP.net / CheckBoxList overwrites values of input List<ListItems>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following scenario: I create a CheckBoxList in my Page_Load (inside (!Page.IsPostBack)), then load some data in my business logic using LINQ. The data produced is a List with different Value and Text properties, which is fine in the moment I call the method (as I checked the return variable with the debugger).

Now as soon as the List object is assigned as the DataSource of my CheckBoxList, using the debugger i realized that the CheckBoxList.Items have overwritten the Item.Value property with the Item.Text property.

So, my desired (and produced) List contains following item, for example:
[image]

However, after DataBind() of my CheckBoxList, this is what the Items look like in the Items collection:
[image]

Is there a clean solution for this problem? My further interest is to compare the Items (found by value) with another list of items (actually the SELECTED items; i thought that giving the CheckBoxList a List of ListItems with the Item.Selected property would be the cleanest way to do it.. nope).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you setting the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` properties of your `CheckBoxList` so it knows which fields/properties in your datasource to map to the value and text properties?

Comment: The `ListItem`'s `Text` returns the `Value` if it is `null`. The same applies to the `Value` property which returns the `Text` if it's `null`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396385/listitem-value-overwrites-text-if-not-set/15396455#15396455 In this case it seems that there's only the `Text`. So you should provide the code instead of images, then we can try to fix it.

Comment: Ben Robinson: no I am not, since I thought that the List<ListItem> would be mapped to match Text/Text and Value/Value (which would make sense, right?). The problem is that these properties are strings, so how can I map the DataValueField to match the Value property of my ListItem, and same for DataTextField / Text property? 

Tim Schmelter: I did stumble upon that similar question, but in my case it is just vice versa - value gets overwritten by text. I can totally provide my code, but I had the feeling this was more of a logical mistake.

Thank you both so far!

Comment: @konrad_pe: as mentioned, the `Value` is overwritten by `Text` if the `Value` is `null` and the `Text` is not and vice versa.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: alright, I get it now. Sorry for being slow on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround, not really solution: instead of giving my CheckBoxList a List as DataSource I provide a DataTable object as DataSource:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Text");
dt.Columns.Add("Value");
```

Instead of creating ListItem objects I create new DataRow objects:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Text"] = "myText";
dr["Value"] = 0001; 
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Finally, I assign the DataTable to my CheckBoxList. The DataValueField and DataTextField strings have to be the same as the column names of the DataTable:

```
myCheckBoxList.DataSource = dt;
myCheckBoxList.DataValueField = "Value";
myCheckBoxList.DataTextField= "Text";
myCheckBoxList.DataBind();
```

In a further step I loop through my CheckBoxList.Items and compare these items with a list of values, setting the ListItem.Selected to true, but since this was not part of the question, I am leaving this behind for now. Please just ask if you need that snippet.